# Weird DATATYPE MISMATCH in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, type-mismatch

I am facing the weirdest error ever:

As for many other tables, I first create the num_iterations table.
Then at one point where I need to update the value, the UPDATE clause is causing a type mismatch error, and what's weird is that updating to a negative value works just fine!
I ran the three below lines independently from the other tables I have in the database and there was no problem!

```
CREATE TABLE num_iterations(val INTEGER);
INSERT INTO num_iterations VALUES (0);
UPDATE num_iterations SET val = 1;
```

Please advise! Thanks

Comment: Can you show the error message here? Created [a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/15aab), works just fine (as you probably expected).

Comment: @raina77ow the error message is exactly "datatype mismatch."

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem. I'm using SQLite version 3.7.15.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8. If you give version information it might help. Also, you might try running the query on a different machine with a different SQLite version.